# Tkinter progress bar during telnet session

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar, telnet

I want to push some configlines through a telnetsession from a tkinter gui.
Simplified; in my GUI I have a button. After pressing this button the telnet session starts (it fetches the config lines from an external fileshare). 
But at this moment it is not very user friendly, there is now way to tell whether it is still busy or not. I want to fix this by a progress bar popup.

I've got my main script with all the fetching of the configuration files, adapting and sending it to a switch.
I got a "standalone" script with the popup progress bar. 
Now I want to combine those two, but it won't work. I've read about multi-threading, but since I'm new to coding I need some help to understand how this works, if it is needed in my case

The mainscript:

```py
#window stuff
window = Tk()
window.geometry('700x500')
window.title("Switchconfig generator")
window.lift()

def btntelnetclicked():
    try:
        telnet()
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo("Status", "Something went wrong, config was not pushed.")

#buttons

btntelnet= Button(window, text="Push config", command=btntelnetclicked)
btntelnet.grid(column=2, row=4, padx=10, pady=10)
```

This is offcourse just a little piece of code

The progressbar

```py
import threading

try: import tkinter
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tkinter
    import ttk
else: from tkinter import ttk

class GUI_Core(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()

        self.progbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.root)
        self.progbar.config(maximum=4, mode='indeterminate')
        self.progbar.pack()

        self.b_start = ttk.Button(self.root, text='Start')
        self.b_start['command'] = self.start_thread
        self.b_start.pack()

    def start_thread(self):
        self.b_start['state'] = 'disable'
        self.progbar.start()
        self.secondary_thread = threading.Thread(target=arbitrary)
        self.secondary_thread.start()
        self.root.after(50, self.check_thread)

    def check_thread(self):
        if self.secondary_thread.is_alive():
            self.root.after(50, self.check_thread)
        else:
            self.progbar.stop()
            self.b_start['state'] = 'normal'


def arbitrary():
    btntelnetclicked()


gui = GUI_Core()
gui.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: instead of `target=arbitrary` you can use `target=btntelnetclicked`. One function less.

Comment: what means "won't work." ? If I use `time.sleep(10)` instead of `btntelnetclicked()` then it works.

Comment: I understand that I have to replace time.sleep(10) with btntelnetclicked(). But my struggle here is how to combine those two scripts. 
 I have my mainscript with the window. In there I have this telnetbutton. Upon pressing this button the progress bar should start, wheter it is a popup or integrated in the main window.
 If I combine those two in the mainscript, first the popup starts and if it's finished, then the mainscript starts.

Comment: When I press button then both run in the same time - it runs function (with `print()` and `sleep()`) and it shows progressbar. Linux Mint, Python 3.7

Comment: I wouldn't integrate `progressbar.py` in `mainscript` but I would import `btntelnetclicked` to `progressbar.py`. But I see other problem - you have two `Tk()` and probably two `mainloop()`. GUI has to use only one `mainloop()` and one main window `Tk()`. For other windows we use `Toplevel()`

Comment: Thanks! I managed to open up and close another screen, using a root() and window()